# Why does maxpathlen error occur during zip->extractto?

Tags: php, zip

I'm using standard php coding to unzip a file on a PC xampp installation, so paths are formatted as C:/ProgramData/etc...

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($zipFile);
if ($res === TRUE) {
  $zip->extractTo($tempPath);
  $zip->close();
}
```

The unzip never completes and the following warning arises:

```
Warning: ZipArchive::extractTo(): Full extraction path exceed MAXPATHLEN (260)
```

While the zip file contains lots of files and folder levels around 8 deep, the longest path names top out at around 150 chars.  Can anyone explain what this error really means?

Comment: You should show the actual value of `$tempPath`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Turns out $tempPath, which also had a few levels, when shortened to simply "temp/", allowed the unzip to complete.